# React: attaching event handlers and/or styles to injected content (svg)

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, svg

What I am trying to do, within a react component, is take a piece of svg, stick it inside a div to render, and then attach mouse event handlers to it's elements. And then I want to dynamically change for example the fill of an element when hovered over or clicked on.

I have browsed a lot of react libraries related to svg, that all do not really seem to do what I need, such as react-svg, react-samy-svg, svg-injector, stuff like that.

Besides they all seem to rely on calling an outside url (i have the content i want to render stored in redux), (and this does not seem to work on my dev server), i am not sure how to attach react-style classNames or onClicks to injected html, or how to store that in the component state.

So now i am falling back on: dangerouslySetInnerHTML to inject the svg content, and dropping a piece of jQuery on it that takes care of the dom manipulations and mouse events, but it's not pretty. Does anyone have another, more react-style, solution? If needed, I can elaborate with pieces of code or whatever. Thanks.